# Get column name of Table based on query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this SQL query

**Query**

```
Select * from `trees` WHERE id = '1' AND ( `apple`='1' OR `banana` = '1' OR `coconut` = '1' OR `pear` ='1') ;
```

And this is my table let's say

**Tree_table**

```
id | apple | banana | coconut | pear|
1     1       1       1           0
2     0       0        1          1
3     1       0        0          1
```

So I want my output to be

```
apple
banana
coconut
```

Is this possible using SQL query or even PHP will do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to *unpivot* the data.  In MySQL, this is probably most easily done with `union all`:

```
select tree
from ((select id, 'apple' as tree
       from trees
       where apple = 1
      ) union all
      (select id, 'banana' as tree
       from trees
       where banana = 1
      ) union all
      (select id, 'coconut' as tree
       from trees
       where coconut = 1
      ) union all
      (select id, 'pear' as tree
       from trees
       where pear = 1
      )
     ) t
where id = 1;
```

Comment: @o3203823 . . . If you specifically need the PHP code, you should ask another question and focus on the PHP aspect of the question.

Comment: no this is fine but i was just wondering on how will one get a php to execute this